# How to retrieve value of a checkbox with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have an issue fetching the value true/false for a checkbox in my webpage with casperjs! I did read several other threads for this subject but it did not solved my issue.

See my webpage code:
[image]

This is my CasperJS code that I have until now and that finds the id that I need for the checkbox:

```
...
    var numTimes = 20,
    count = -1;
    casper.repeat(numTimes, function() {
        var name = this.evaluate(function(count) {
            var sel = '[id*="connectedToNeType[' + count + ']"]';
            var element = document.querySelector(sel).id;
            return element;
        }, ++count);
        var check_id = name.replace(/_TD|_TR/, '');
        var checked = this.evaluate(function(check_id) {
            var element = document.getElementById(check_id).checked;
            return element;
        });
        this.echo(' checkbox: ' + checked);
    });
```

I am using repeat because I have multiple id's that I need to check the value of the check boxes!

The variable *name* would fetch the several id's from similar lines like the below line:

[image]

In an example page, I get the below printout when running the above CasperJS:

```
-> connectedToNeType[0]}
 checkbox: null
-> connectedToNeType[1]}
 checkbox: null
-> connectedToNeType[2]}
 checkbox: null
-> connectedToNeType[3]}
 checkbox: null
-> connectedToNeType[4]}
 checkbox: null
-> connectedToNeType[5]}
 checkbox: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass in the `check_id` into the second `evaluate()` call. Also, your checkbox ends in "_CB" which you haven't added.

It seems you want:

```
var name = this.evaluate(function(count) {
    var sel = '[id*="connectedToNeType[' + count + ']"]';
    var element = document.querySelector(sel).id;
    return element;
}, ++count);
var check_id = name.replace(/_TD|_TR/, '') + '_CB';
var checked = this.evaluate(function(check_id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(check_id).checked;
    return element;
}, check_id);
this.echo(' checkbox: ' + checked);
```